# Automorphism group of finite $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

firstly I  apologize for my naive knowledge in group theory.

Let  $G$  be  a  finite  $p$-group with automorphism group ${\rm Aut}(G)$
and  let  $N$  be  a  maximal  subgroup  of $G$.  Let  $g$  be  an  element  of G  with  $G  =  \langle g, N\rangle $
and  let  $\rho$  denote  the  automorphism  of  $N$  induced  by  conjugation  by  $g$.  If  $u$  is  an 
element  of $N$, let  $\mu_u$  denote  conjugation  in  $N$  by  $u$.   Then  there  is  a  bijection  between 
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&A_\alpha:=\{\phi\in {\rm Aut}(G)\ |\ \phi{|}_N=\alpha,  \phi{|}_{G/N}=1_{G/N} \},\\
&&N_\alpha:=\{u\in N\ |\ [\rho,\alpha]=\mu_u, (g^p)^{\alpha}=(gu)^p\}
\end{eqnarray*}
given  by  $\phi\longrightarrow g^{-1}g^{\phi}$.

Please give me more details about the following  fact:

If  $\alpha$   has  order  a  power of $p$   so  does  any  element of  $A_\alpha$.

Notation: ‌‌By the symbols $g^{\phi}$ and $\phi{|}_N$.
I mean the image of $g$ under $\phi$ and restriction of $\phi$  to $N$, respectively.
 Also $[\rho,\alpha]=\rho^{-1}\alpha^{-1}\rho\alpha$ denotes 
commutator of $\rho$ and $\alpha$.

Thank you very much.

Edit:Since $|G/N|=p$, then any element of $G$ is of the form $g^in$, where $1\leq i\leq p-1$ and $n\in N$. 
How could   we  show that  $(g^in)^{{\phi }^{p^t}}=g^in$ for some $t\geq 1$.

Comment: it never hurts to recallthat a maximal subgroup of a p-group is always normal.

Comment: Dear Mariano, of course! But how could this help us?

Comment: Let $a^{p^n}=1$, then $\phi|_N^{p^n}=1$, but $\phi|_{G/N}^{p^n}=1^{p^n}=1$, so that we have $\phi^{p^n}=1$.

Comment: @sebastian To make sense of the action of conjugation, you need to assume that $N$ is normal, almost by definition!

Comment: You used that fact to be able to construct $\rho$. Since a lot of the people reading your question is probably know aware of this fact, recalling it helps them.